# Sklearn: Surprising Behavior with TfidfVectorizer

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm using Pandas and Sklearn for a Kaggle competition.  I'm using `TfidfVectorizer` to get a feature for the top 100 most important features from each of the `Title` and `FullDescription` columns.  I'm prepending "TITLE_" before words that occur in the `Title` and "DESC_" before words that occur in the `FullDescription`.

Unfortunately, one of my rows (the 10,000th one) is valid before I modify anything in my DataFrame:

```
df.iloc[9999]
```

Gives me:

```
Id                                                             66190737
Title                                      Experienced RHAD Job Lincoln
FullDescription       We provide a community hearing service to thos...
LocationRaw                                       Lincoln, Lincolnshire
LocationNormalized                                              Lincoln
ContractType                                                  full_time
ContractTime                                                        NaN
Company                                                             NaN
Category                                      Healthcare & Nursing Jobs
SalaryRaw                                     18,000 to 40,000 per year
SalaryNormalized                                                  29000
SourceName                                               careworx.co.uk
Name: 9999, dtype: object
```

Once I use `TfidfVectorizer`, all of the features in the 10,000th row from `Title` or `FullDescription` (the ones prepended with "TITLE_" or "DESC_") are `NaN`.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
STEMMER = nltk.stem.porter.PorterStemmer()
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')

def stem_tokens(tokens, stemmer=STEMMER):
    return [stemmer.stem(item) for item in tokens]
def tokenize(text, tokenizer=tokenizer):
    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
    return stem_tokens(tokens)

def get_tfidf_df(df, col, max_features, prefix, tokenize):
    vec = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize, stop_words="english", max_features=max_features)
    tfidf = vec.fit_transform(df[col])
    tfidf_array = tfidf.toarray()
    tfidf_df = pd.DataFrame(tfidf_array, columns=vec.get_feature_names())
    tfidf_df.columns = [prefix + "_" + str(col) for col in tfidf_df.columns]
    return tfidf_df

def group_rare_entries(df, col, threshold):
    mask = df[col].groupby(df[col]).transform("count").lt(threshold)
    df[col][mask] = "RARE"

def address_rare_entries(df, cols, threshold):
    for col in cols:
        group_rare_entries(df, col, threshold)

def get_processed_df(df, rare_cols, threshold=10):
    address_rare_entries(df, rare_cols, threshold)
    df = df[pd.notnull(df["FullDescription"]) & pd.notnull(df["Title"]) & pd.notnull(df["SalaryNormalized"])]
    tfidf_desc = get_tfidf_df(df, "FullDescription", max_features=100, prefix="DESC", tokenize=tokenize)
    tfidf_title = get_tfidf_df(df, "Title", max_features=100, prefix="TITLE", tokenize=tokenize)
    df.drop("FullDescription", inplace=True, axis=1)
    df.drop("Title", inplace=True, axis=1)
    final_df = pd.concat([df, tfidf_desc, tfidf_title], axis=1)
    return final_df


final_df = get_processed_df(df, rare_cols=["LocationNormalized", "Company", "Category", "SourceName"], threshold=10)
```

Then, when I look at my 10,000th row with:

```
final_df.iloc[9999].isnull().sum()
```

I get back:

```
202
```

I manually inspect and all my `TITLE_` and `DESC_` features in that row are `NaN`.

Any idea what's going on here?  I'm a little suspicious that this only seems to happen on the very last row...

Thanks!

Comment: What does the `vec.fit_transform([df.iloc[9999]['Title']])` and `vec.fit_transform([df.iloc[9999]['FullDescription']])` returns?

Comment: @VivekKumar title
   ```(0, 0) 0.5
  (0, 3) 0.5
  (0, 1) 0.5
  (0, 2) 0.5
desc
   (0, 63) 0.0478364873235
  (0, 9) 0.191345949294
  (0, 24) 0.287018923941
  (0, 85) 0.14350946197
  (0, 97) 0.0478364873235
  (0, 96) 0.0478364873235
  (0, 25) 0.191345949294
  (0, 89) 0.095672974647
  (0, 54) 0.095672974647
  (0, 22) 0.14350946197
  (0, 65) 0.0478364873235
  : :```

Comment: @VivekKumar So the output doesn't look too strange to me...